# how to increase of cellvaluechanged event in devexpress?

Tags: events, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit in gridview. when I choose an item in repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit, this event is running. According to st_id, I assign 30 values to a specific cell. this event is working. all cells are filling, but there is problem which is performans. how to increase performance of this event?

```
    private void gridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e){
            var st_id = gridView.GetRowCellValue(gridView.FocusedRowHandle, gcStokkodu.FieldName);if (st_id == 0) return;
            var stok = _stokTableAdapter.GetDataById(Convert.ToInt32(st_id)).FirstOrDefault();
                gridView.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridView.Columns[gcStokKod.FieldName], stok.ST_KOD);gridView.SetRowCellValue(...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a flag to determine whether code in the CellValueChanged event handler can be executed. For example:

bool lockCellValueChanged;
        private void GridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lockCellValueChanged)
                return;
            lockCellValueChanged = true;
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Column", newValue);
            lockCellValueChanged = false;
        }